# rsync --delete --files-from=list / dest/ does not delete unwanted files

Tags: rsync

As you can see in the title I try to sync a folder with a list of files. I hoped that this command would delete all files in dest/ that are not on the list, but it didn't.

So I searched a little bit and know now, that rsync can't do this.

But I need it, so do you know any way to do it?

PS: The list is created by a python script, so it is imaginable that your solution uses some python code.

EDIT, let's be concrete:

The list looks like this:

```
/home/max/Musik/Coldplay/Parachutes/Trouble.mp3
/home/max/Musik/Coldplay/Parachutes/Yellow.mp3
/home/max/Musik/Coldplay/A Rush of Blood to the Head/Warning Sign.mp3
/home/max/Musik/Coldplay/A Rush of B-Sides to Your Head/Help Is Around the Corner.mp3
/home/max/Musik/Coldplay/B-Sides (disc 3)/Bigger Stronger.mp3
```

and the command like this:

```
rsync --delete --files-from=/tmp/list / /home/max/Desktop/foobar/
```

This works, but if I delete a line, it is not deleted in foobar/.

EDIT 2:

```
rsync -r --include-from=/tmp/list --exclude=* --delete-excluded / /home/max/Desktop/foobar/
```

That works neither ...

Comment: Btw.: rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30
forgot that, sorry

Comment: One of the things I hate most about rsync, is that lack of support for exactly what you are asking for. Good post.

Comment: Until now, 2022, rsync still doesn't support this feature :)). I still face the same issue, but I have to rsync many files and extensions so I cannot use the solution --include-from that in the accepted comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps you could do this using a list of include patterns instead, and use `--delete-excluded` (which does as the name suggests)? Something like:

```
rsync -r --include-from=<patternlistfile> --exclude=* --delete-excluded / dest/
```

If filenames are likely to contain wildcard characters (`*`, `?` and `[`) then you may need to modify the Python to escape them:

```
re.sub("([[*?])", r"\\\1", "abc[def*ghi?klm")
```

**Edit:** Pattern-based matching works slightly differently to `--files-from` in that `rsync` won't recurse into directories that match the exclude pattern, for reasons of efficiency. So if your files are in `/some/dir` and `/some/other/dir` then your pattern file needs to look like:

```
/some/
/some/dir/
/some/dir/file1
/some/dir/file2
/some/other/
/some/other/dir/
/some/other/dir/file3
...
```

Alternatively, if all files are in the same directory then you could rewrite the command slightly:

```
rsync -r --include-from=<patternlistfile> --exclude=* --delete-excluded /some/dir/ dest/
```

and then your patterns become:

```
/file1
/file2
```

**Edit:** Thinking about it, you could include all directories with one pattern:

```
/**/
```

but then you'd end up with the entire directory tree in `dest/` which probably isn't what you want. But combining it with `-m` (which prunes empty directories) should solve that - so the command ends up something like:

```
rsync -m -r --delete-excluded --include-from=<patternfile> --exclude=* / dest/
```

and the pattern file:

```
/**/
/some/dir/file1
/some/other/dir/file3
```

Comment: Thank you, too, but your command ask for -d or -r and neither work.

Comment: Are the files in a subdirectory? If so, the directory (and its parents) need to be in the pattern list as well, otherwise rsync won't even recurse into them.

Comment: I think at this point, it is worth to test your commands on your system first :P

Comment: AAAAHHH, now i get it. I have to write all parent dirs in the list.

Comment: Works fine here (apart from missing off -r first time round - that'll teach me for re-typing). I was hoping you'd check the man page and adapt my commands to your situation rather than blindly copy+pasting, though ;)

Comment: You might not need to, actually - depending on what you want to do with empty directories. Another edit coming up...

Comment: Now it finally works as it should. Thank you so much. I wish i could vote this answer up.

Comment: Just used this to sync an MPD playlist. I had to manually prepend an '/**/' the playlist though. I wish there was some way to not need that part.

Comment: Amazing answer, the last solution saved my day.

Comment: So if the source directory is `./`, the first pattern should be `./**/` ? Also, if you don't want to edit your pattern file, can you simply have a `--include='./**/'` *and* a `--include-from=filelist` options?

Answer (score 13):

This is not exactly the solution, but people coming here might find this useful: Since rsync 3.1.0 there is a `--delete-missing-args` parameter which deletes files in the destination directory when you sync two directories using `--files-from`. You would need to specify the deleted files in `/tmp/list` along with files you do want copied:

```
rsync --delete-missing-args --files-from=/tmp/list /source/dir /destination/dir
```

See [the man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) for more details.

Comment: Looked promising, but I had misunderstood what this option does. It will only delete files on the destination if they are listed in the --files-from list but cannot be found on the source.

Comment: isn't that exactly what was required.

Answer (score 10):

As you explained, the command

```
rsync -r --delete --files-from=$FILELIST user@server:/ $DEST/
```

does not delete content in the destination when an entry from $FILELIST has been removed. A simple solution is to use instead the following.

```
mkdir -p $DEST
rm -rf $TEMP
rsync -r --link-dest=$DEST --files-from=$FILELIST user@server:/ $TEMP/
rm -r $DEST
mv $TEMP $DEST
```

This instructs rsync to use an empty destination. Files that are already present in the link-dest-directory are locally hard-linked and not copied. Finally the old destination is replaced by the new one. The first mkdir creates an empty $DEST if $DEST doesn't exist, to prevent rsync error. (The $-variables are assumed to carry the full path to the respective file or directory.)

There is some minor overhead for the hard-linking, but you don't need to mess with complex include/exclude-strategies.

Comment: Interesting solution! Too bad there is no such trick when synchronizing _from_ local _to_ the server.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired from m4t, but using ... rsync for cleanup

```
rsync -r --link-dest=$dest --files-from=filelist.txt user@server:$source/ $temp
rsync -ra --delete --link-dest=$temp $temp/ $dest
```

Comment: 'rm -rf $TEMP' is needed before your code, otherwise, if $temp has unwanted files in it, they will end up in $dest.

Comment: I think theres a typo here, not exactly sure where

Answer (score 1):

Explicit build --exclude-from=... seems the only way to synchronize list of files.

```
stdin = subprocess.PIPE
other_params.append("--exclude-from=-") #from stdin 

p = subprocess.Popen( 'rsync -e ssh -zthvcr --compress-level=9 --delete'.split() + other_params + [src, dst], stdin =  PIPE)

if relative_files_list != None:
    #hack: listing of excluded files seems the only way to delete unwanted files at destination
    files = set(map(norm_fn, relative_files_list)) #make hash table, for huge lists
    for path, ds, fs in os.walk(src):
        for f in fs:
            rel_path_f = norm_fn(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(path, f), src))
            if rel_path_f not in files:
                #print 'excluding', rel_path_f.replace('\\', '/')
                p.stdin.write(rel_path_f + '\n')
    p.stdin.close()
assert 0 == p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a long time ago, but I wasn't satisfied with the answer.

Here is how I solved the problem, assuming a playlist created by `mpd`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                 

playlist_path="/home/cpbills/.config/mpd/playlists"
playlist="${playlist_path}/${1}.m3u"
music_src="/home/cpbills/files/music"
music_dst="/mnt/sdcard/music/"

if [[ -e "$playlist" ]]; then
  # Remove old files
  find "$music_dst" -type f | while read file; do
    name="$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s!^$music_dst!!")"
    if ! grep -qF "$name" "$playlist"; then
      rm "$file"
    fi
  done

  # Remove empty directories
  find "$music_dst" -type d -exec rmdir {} \; 2>/dev/null

  rsync -vu \
      --inplace \
      --files-from="$playlist" \
      "$music_src" "$music_dst"
else
  printf "%s does not exist\n" "$playlist" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on 131's and m4t's answers, I took this approach:

1. `mv $dest $dest2`
2. `mkdir $dest`
3. `rsync (args incl --files-from...) --link-dest=$dest2 $dest2 $dest`
4. `rm -rf $dest2`

All operations are nearly free, no copying or temporary space required beyond filesystem bookkeeping

You can then run your usual rsync command from $source to $dest, and you will be left with exactly what is in files-from.

Answer (score -1):

**rsync** is ideal for keeping directories in sync, among other useful things.  If you do have an exact copy on the SOURCE, and want to delete files on the DEST, you can delete them from SOURCE and the `rsync --delete` option will delete them from DEST also.

**However**, if you just have an arbitrary list of files you want to delete, I suggest you use SSH to accomplish that:

```
ssh user@remote.host.com rm /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

This will execute the `rm` command on the remote host.

**Using python, you could:**

```
import subprocess
FileList = ['/path/to/file1', '/path/to/file2']
subprocess.call(['ssh', 'dAnjou@my.server.com', 'rm'] + FileList)
```

~enjoy

Comment: Misunderstanding.
I don't have a list of files to delete. I have a list of files to copy. I want those files that are NOT on the list to be deleted.

But thanks for your answer.